# Table join to return results in one row.

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have two tables and need to  create a mysql view that gives the results in one row.

Currently I use a join but that gives me records as rows rather than columns. I tried the pivot but cannot get it to work. I need the hours for paint, hours for plumb and Other (everything else is in other) per job in one row.

The table structure is here:

[image]

Comment: "Currently I use a join". Can you paste the query you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a `PIVOT`, unfortunately MySQL does not have a PIVOT function, but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select jobnum,
  sum(case when tasktype = 'paint' then hrs else 0 end) Paint,
  sum(case when tasktype = 'plumb' then hrs else 0 end) plumb,
  sum(case when tasktype not in ('paint', 'Plumb') then hrs else 0 end) Other
from tablea a
left join tableb b
  on a.id = b.tbla_id
group by jobnum
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a504e/2)

Result:

```
| JOBNUM | PAINT | PLUMB | OTHER |
----------------------------------
|      1 |    10 |    10 |    20 |
|      2 |    25 |     0 |     0 |
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    a.`JobNum`,
    SUM(IF(a.`TaskType`='Paint',b.`Hrs`,0)) AS 'Paint',
    SUM(IF(a.`TaskType`='Plumb',b.`Hrs`,0)) AS 'Plumb',
    SUM(IF(a.`TaskType` IN('Paint','Plumb'),0,b.`Hrs`)) AS 'Other'
FROM `tableA` a
INNER JOIN `tableB` b
ON b.`tblAid`=a.`id`
GROUP BY a.`JobNum`
```

Comment: I did not do a downvote! I actually said that the post was useful to me.

Comment: To expand this, if Table B had another column - include yes/no. how would we incorporate that in the query?

Comment: That wasn't for you, it was to the downvoter. As with your question, it all depends on what you're expecting as the result. Additional suggestion: Create a column with datatype `TINYINT` and use the values 0 or 1 for the value, for boolean situations. That will help consume the least space and processing time possible in a database. If you need an "unset" value there, just set it to accept `NULL`.